# How to assert response in zipoutputstream

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, spring-test-mvc

I am trying to write JUnit using MockitoJUnitRunner.
I am passing file id to my function which is downloading file from cloud and returning zip file as download.
here is my code

```
public void getLogFile(HttpServletResponse response, String id) throws IOException {

    response.setContentType("Content-type: application/zip");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=LogFiles.zip");

    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(out));

    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(id));

    InputStream inputStream = someDao.getFile(id);

    BufferedInputStream fif = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

    int data = 0;

    while ((data = fif.read()) != -1) {
        zos.write(data);
    }

    fif.close();

    zos.closeEntry();
    zos.close();
}
```

And my JUnit function is

```
@Mock
private MockHttpServletResponse mockHttpServletResponse;

anyInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("test data".getBytes());

    @Test
    public void shouldDownloadFile() throws IOException {

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);

        when(mockHttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(outputStream);


 =>          when(someDao.download(anyString())).thenReturn(anyInputStream);


        controller.getLogFile(mockHttpServletResponse, id);

        verify(mockHttpServletResponse).setContentType("Content-type: application/zip");

        verify(mockHttpServletResponse).setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=LogFiles.zip");

        verify(atmosdao).download(atmosFilePath);
    }
```

This unit test is passing but I want to verify what is written on outputStream, how can I do it ? as I am writing "test data" to mocked outputStream like

```
anyInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("test data".getBytes());

when(someDao.download(anyString())).thenReturn(anyInputStream);
```

`mockHttpServletResponse.getContentAsString()` is giving me null !

Is it possible to assert `MockHttpServletResponse` which is written using zipoutputStream ? if yes then how can i do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mocking your `OutputStream`, you could create a custom one:

```
public class CustomOutputStream extends ServletOutputStream {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private String content;

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {
        out.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        content = new String(out.toByteArray());
        out.close();
        super.close();
    }

    public String getContentAsString() {
        return this.content; 
    }
}
```

This class will store all the bytes written to it and keep them in the `content` field.

Then you replace this:

```
ServletOutputStream outputStream = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);
```

by this:

```
CustomOutputStream outputStream = new CustomOutputStream();
```

When your servlet calls `getOutputStream()`, it will use the custom one, and in the end `getContentAsString()` will return you the output that was written to your servlet.

**Note:** the output is zipped, so the String will contain strange characters. If you want the original string, you'll have to unzip it (and in this case I'd use the byte array returned by `out.toByteArray()` instead of the String, because when you create a String this way you can have encoding problems when calling `string.getBytes()`)

Comment: Hi Hugo, is there a way to check if zip file is present in outputstream ?

Comment: The outputstream is **writing** to a zip file (actually, it's generating "zipped" bytes), so the zip file will only exist after some client calls the servlet and saves these bytes to a file. Is that what you asked or I misunderstood?

Comment: Actually I want to assert in junit whether servletoutputstream has zip file (zipoutputstream) or not ?

Comment: I don't think you need to assert it. When you do `when(mockHttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(outputStream)` you're saying that your servlet already has an outputstream (because it'll be returned, as it's already mocked). Instead, I would assert the result (`getContentAsString`, or even better, the bytes used to build it -  the ones returned in `out.toByteArray()`). As your input is always the same ("test data"), it'd be easy to check the zipped bytes.

Answer (score 1):

I got what I was looking for...
This is what I did to assert data written to zipoutputStream using powerMockito.

```
@Test
public void ShouldAttemptToWriteDownloadedFileToZipOutputStream() throws Exception {

    InputStream anyInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("test data".getBytes());

    ServletOutputStream outputStream = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);

    BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = Mockito.mock(BufferedOutputStream.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedOutputStream.class).withArguments(outputStream).thenReturn(bufferedOutputStream);

    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = Mockito.mock(ZipOutputStream.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ZipOutputStream.class).withArguments(bufferedOutputStream).thenReturn(zipOutputStream);

    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(anyInputStream);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(BufferedInputStream.class).withArguments(anyInputStream).thenReturn(bufferedInputStream);

    subjectUnderTest.getLogFile(mockHttpServletResponse, "12345");

    int data = 0;

    while ((data = bufferedInputStream.read()) != -1) {

        verify(zipOutputStream).write(data);
    }
}
```

Thanks Hugo for your help !